# how to show selected images in listview?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, listadapter

In my app I can access the gallery through the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

now through `startActivityForresult();` I can get the `URI` of selected image. I add the URI in an `ArrayList<String> imageList`, I want to show the images in a ListView by another Activity.
please help??

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. I did not understand your question.

Comment: I want to select the images from Gallery and show them in to a list view.

Comment: I got now. Will you please like to share your getView() method code used in ListAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can send that list to Another `Activity` with `ListView` or *Make It Public To be Accesed From Another Activity*

and in `Adapter's getView` method while assigning `Image to ImageView` do it like this,

```
Uri contentUri = imageList.get(position);
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String tmppath = cursor.getString(column_index);

Bitmap imaage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmppath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```